# Running Javascript to size an ASP.NET control once it is rendered or updated by a postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, page-lifecycle, ascx

I have an ascx control that is loaded in an aspx page.
How can I instruct my ascx to run javascript once it is rendered in the browser.
It should run on every postback as well.

I looked around but could not find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the "RegisterStartupScript" method along with JQuery to call a JS function?
This code might help you:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(Page), "myScript", "$(function() {{ alert ('Your page is loaded.'); }});", True)
```

You can replace the alert with any JS function you want :)

I hope this helps.